# Looping elements in WebdriverIO

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to loop through a list of links, and perform some actions with each one. I can iterate the elements using [elements](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html), but using [click](http://webdriver.io/api/action/click.html) inside the forEach doesn't block the next step in forEach, and Selenium goes nuts, as it tries to continue doing actions on elements not in the DOM anymore.

```
var q = require("q");
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

var clicks = [];

var runner = webdriverio.remote(options);

runner
    .init()
    .url('https://www.google.dk/search?q=burrito')
    .elements(".r").then(function(res){
        res.value.forEach(function(elem){
            console.log(elem);
            clicks.push(
                runner
                    .elementIdClick(elem.ELEMENT)
                    .pause(5000)
                    .back()
                    .pause(2000)
            );
        });

        return q.all(clicks);
    });
```

How do I make sure the next iteration in the forEach doesn't run before all the code is executed inside the forEach?

Edit: I should have mentioned that I already tried https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/941 and https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/273. I updated my code sample with something more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this response](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/1043) from the creator of WebdriverIO, the correct way to loop through some links and click them:

```
runner
    .init()
    .url('https://www.google.dk/search?q=burrito')
    .getText(".r").then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
        res.forEach(function(elem){
            console.log(elem);
            clicks.push(
                runner
                    .click('=' + elem)
                    .back()
            );
        });

        return q.all(clicks);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var runner = webdriverjs
.remote(options)
.init()
.url("http://www.google.com")

 // fetch elements
.elements('a', function(err, res){
    // iterate through elements
    res.value.forEach(function(elem) {
        // execute specific action
        runner.elementIdClick(elem.Element, function(err, res) {
             // callback logic here
             // ...
        })
    })
})
```

from https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/273

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already tried the solutions I could find on github. I updated my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Async package for something like that.

http://caolan.github.io/async/

```
async.eachSeries(hugeArray, function iteratee(item, callback) {
    if (inCache(item)) {
        callback(null, cache[item]); // if many items are cached, you'll overflow
    } else {
        doSomeIO(item, callback);
    }
}, function done() {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to extract text from the list of elements

```html
I am able to extract text for the list of webelements and then store it to the Array .


var strColumntext = [] ;
    var table =browser.$(".//*/table/tbody");

   table.$$(".//tr/th").map(function(element){
         console.log("Extracted text is : "+element.getText());
         strColumntext.push(element.getText());
    });
    
    console.log("Print the all texts : "+strColumntext)
```

[You can see Youtube Demo for this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWc0Sv404XE&list=PLXBKC3hh6AEr5dMdptmk5-S5_yyHKQ4cW&index=4)